# Remove the "Assign to contact" option in the iOS Share Sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a Share Sheet that shares an image and I want to get rid of the "Add to Contacts" option. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `excludedActivityTypes` property of the `UIActivityViewController`. Pass in `UIActivityTypeAssignToContact`.

```
UIActivityViewController avc = ... // create the activity view
avc.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypeAssignToContact ];
// now present the activity view controller
```

Comment: UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[ image ] applicationActivities:nil  ];
  [topViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    
    controller.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypeAssignToContact ];

Comment: You have to set the excluded activities before you present it.